# Firebase Node SDK ref.on and ref.once not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been using firebase for a couple years now and I've not run into this - I believe it is Google Account/Firebase Account related.

This basic code will not get into the ref.on() or ref.once() function - either the success or error callbacks.  What is the deal?

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require('../firebase-security.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://swc-shockball3.firebaseio.com/'
});

var db = admin.database();

console.log('trying to get ref .once')
var itemsRef = db.ref('items');

itemsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
   // never gets here
  console.log(snapshot)
}, function(error) {
  // doesn't get here either
  console.log('error is')
  console.log(error)
})
```

I've found if I console.log the itemsRef itself it will return a largish firebase-y object.  I also can log itemsRef.once.toString() and it will log the function signature, but CALLING it doesn't actually work correctly.

I ensured my permissions for the database are read/write as true (boolean).  I've ensured that the json for my serviceAccount is correct-  I even blew away my firebase project altogether and created a new one.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I turned on admin.database.enableLogging(true) and could then see the error message was Googal OAuth token invalid grant error.  I created a new service account, no change.

But then I simply changed my local machine (Windows 10) time settings to be automatic time/automatic date.  That fixed it!

Comment: Thank you !!! I've had the same error for three hours and I was desperate. Thank you.